# React Native: unique key for list of images shown in grids

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my `React Native` 0.63.2 app, images are displayed in grid which is 2 or 3 grids in a row. A single image is rendered with `DisplayImg` and `image_array.map()` is being used to iterate through each and every image and render it with `DisplayImg`. Here is the `map` code (for size of image of 4 or less):

```
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
....
return (
                <Grid style={{position:"absolute", paddingTop:0,paddingLeft:0}}>
                    {pics.map((item, index) => {
                        if (index%2===0) {  //<<==for even # of images, full rows of 2 grids
                            if (pics[index+1]) {
                                return (
                                    <Row style={styles.row}>
                                        <View key={pics[index]}>  //<<==View here is to wrap each `DisplayImg` with unique `key`
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index].fileName)}
                                            width={screen_width*half}
                                            ht={screen_width*half}
                                            index= {index}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index].height*(screen_width/pics[index].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                                        />
                                        </View>  
                                        <View key={pics[index+1].fileName}>
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index+1])}
                                            width={screen_width*half}
                                            ht={screen_width*half}
                                            index= {index+1}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index+1].height*(screen_width/pics[index+1].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage}                                           
                                        />           
                                        </View>                  
                                    </Row>    
                                )} else {  //<<==last row with one image only
                                return (
                                    <Row style={styles.row}>
                                        <View key={pics[index].fileName}>
                                        <DisplayImg 
                                            img_source={picPath(pics[index])}
                                            width={screen_width*half}
                                            ht={screen_width*half}
                                            index= {index}
                                            modalWidth={screen_width}
                                            modalHt= {pics[index].height*(screen_width/pics[index].width)}
                                            dataLen={len}
                                            sortFn={move}
                                            handleSwipe={swipeImage}                                          
                                        />
                                        </View>
                                    </Row>    
                                )};                                           
                        }
                    })}                        
                </Grid>
            );
```

But the app throw warning about missing unique `key` prop. Here is the warning message:

```
[Tue Aug 25 2020 15:44:16.593]  ERROR    Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the top-level render call using <GridNB>. See h-t-t-p-s:/-/fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.
    in RowNB (at DisplayImages.js:255)  //<<==RowNB is method provide by Row from react-native-easy-grid
    in Unknown (at Itie.js:200)  //<<==Itie is a function component of the app itself
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at MyAccordion.js:57)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at MyAccordion.js:56)
    in MyAccordion (at Itie.js:199)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ScrollView.js:1124)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1260)
    in ScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1286)
    in ScrollView (at KeyboardAwareHOC.js:487)
    in KeyboardAwareScrollView (at Content.js:37)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at SafeAreaView.js:41)
    in ForwardRef(SafeAreaView) (at Content.js:36)
    in Content (at connectStyle.js:392)
    in Styled(Content) (at Itie.js:182)
    .....
```

I am following the [React document](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) here unique key. What is wrong here with the `key` for each `DisplayImg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the key for root component that is returned by the map callback. In your case it should be something like this `<Row style={styles.row} key={index}>`. Please note that you should add `key` in both your return statements.

Comment: This is the error message says. But each `Row` has 2 image grids and each individual image is still not uniquely keyed. When the last image is deleted, then the row key can be the same but the content of Row has changed. The key in Row will not be able to uniquely identify a Row and this defeats the purpose of the key